# Characterization of Closed Sets in the Reals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

It is known that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals. The same cannot be said for closed sets. For example, a closed set could contain some union of closed intervals or even sets like $\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$. Taking this into account, I ask the following question:

> Can every closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ be written as a countable disjoint union of positive measure closed intervals and a set of measure zero?

Any hints, observations, and solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Even  the real line it self (which is closed) can't  be partitioned by closed disjoint intervals. See https://www.google.com/amp/s/terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/covering-a-non-closed-interval-by-disjoint-closed-intervals/amp/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Look up “fat Cantor set.” A closed set is the complement of an open set, so negating the description of open sets gives you a description of closed sets. I do not think this is actually that useful.  Closed subsets are very complicated in general. Even if you go to $\mathbf R^n$ for $n > 1$, the elementary description of open sets in the real line has no analogue.

Answer (score 2):

While your statement is false, what's true is that every closed subset of $\mathbb R$ is the disjoint union of a [perfect set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set) and a countable set. This is not obvious!